# Using middleware to call an Authentication API using ExpressJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, express

I'm using two Node.js + Express applications:

- Backend
- Authentication

And my front-end is built in AngularJS

Basically I'm trying to send a json web token with every request to the Backend, and then use a route middleware to call the Authentication API. It validates that token and add user data to the request. Finally, I'm handling the request on the backend using the user data to get my resource.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [<dependencies>
]).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
        })
        .when('/foo', {
            templateUrl: 'views/foo.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: '404.html'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: false,
        requireBase: false
    });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', '$sessionStorage', function($q, $location, $sessionStorage) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                if ($sessionStorage.token) {
                    config.headers.Authorization = $sessionStorage.token;
                }
                return config;
            },
            'responseError': function (response) {
                if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
                    $location.path('/');
                }
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    }]);
});
```

Then, my middleware handlers in the backend look like this:

```
var router = express.Router(); 
// middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    'use strict';
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    next(); 
});

//middleware to validate token
router.use('/foos', function (req, res, next) {
    'use strict';
    var token = req.headers.authorization;
    console.log(token);
    authorizeRequest(token);
    next();
});

router.get('/foos', function (req, res) {
    'use strict';
    actividadController.getActividad(req, res);

});

app.use('/api', router);

app.listen(8080);
```

The authorizeRequest function makes a call to the Authentication API.

My problem is that both middlewares are called twice on each request and I can't find the reason why it's happening.

Comment: When you look in the browser's network activity, do you see the request being fired twice?

Comment: I'm seeing that it's called one with GET and another one with OPTIONS, maybe that is what makes the middleware gets fired twice, right?

Comment: Exactly correct.  I've posted an answer detailing how I would solve this problem.  I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the middleware is being fired from the `OPTIONS` request.  Using a more robust express library like [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) will solve this problem.

Alternatively, you could check for the `OPTIONS` request manually, then return the necessary information instead of calling `next()`, but unless you know exactly what you're doing, I wouldn't recommend that.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've made an approach by http method instead of url.

Instead of router.use I'm using router. and a regex to describe the uri.

```
router.get('/user/:username/*', function (req, res, next) {
    'use strict';
    var token = req.headers.authorization;
    http.get('http://localhost:10020/api/tokens/' + token, function (response) {
        if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.status(response.statusCode).json({ message: "Rejected" });
        }
    });
});
```